Are there actually hidden questions?
The text 'Hiding questions because of your Ignored tags preferences for tags:' appears at the bottom of the 'front page' https://meta.stackexchange.com/

I read this as 'a filter is active', but I'm more interested in 'some/nnn questions were filtered out'....
Is the wording ambiguous? How can I know if questions were actually left out?

If you filter out questions you won't see them. If you want to see all questions, stop filtering some out. It seems the system is doing what you told it to and now you're confused because it's behaving as it's supposed to do.

Relatated/dupe.

You cannot, at least not on that page. You can't even count the number of questions and check if it's lower than the default, because the hidden questions will be replaced with older (less recently active) ones.
Of course, you can click the tag(s), but that kind-of defeats the purpose of ignoring them.

Also possible to ignore the tags but not set the ignored tags to hide. Then questions with the ignored tags will still show up with a grey background.

because the hidden questions will be replaced with older (less recently active) ones -> isn't this false? I thought the questions would be filtered out on the client side, and no further questions are fetched from the backend. At least this information was told to me some years ago.

@Lino the client-side filtering happens on the /questions page (and also custom filters and so on) but not on the homepage. There you always get a full list of items even when you exclude some tags. Unless you set the ignored tags to be greyed out, then on the homepage they also show up and you get the same total number of items

Oh, I didn't notice that the OP was talking about the homepage, got it @VLAZ
